# How to mount a github repository on Windows/Linux with SMB/NFS?

Tags: git, github, nfs, smb, nas

Clarifying the exact requirement. Is there any way where one can access github (full) or specific repository as shared path or mounted drive using SMB or NFS protocol?

Eg:
Simulated NAS device: github.com

Similated NAS Share Path: <repository name>

With credentials as gihub is credentials protected

is there any way to achieve this?

Note: dont provide any solution that would require user to use git commands as git init/clone/pull etc. All I want is pure NAS solution to access files in my git repository

Comment: I'm pretty sure GitHub itself doesn't serve anything publicly via either SMB or NFS. The actual content of files can be accessed via HTTPS on `raw.githubusercontent.com` links like [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openjdk/jdk/master/README.md), but AFAIK that doesn't provide directory listings. Your best bet is probably to run some script on your NAS that regularly mirrors the github repo and then expose that clone via SMB/NFS. Most NAS these days allow running docker containers for tasks like this.

Comment: The question is unclear. Github is a site, not the Git version control program. And Git isn't a network or file sharing protocol. You can store Git repositories on remote file shares without doing any extra work - just make sure you use the corrects path in git commands.

Comment: Besides what does `access github (full) or specific repository as shared path or mounted drive` mean? Git isn't a file system, it works on a file system. The actual data it tracks is inside the `.git` folder in an unusable format. That's what you get when you use `git init --bare`. The files developers work with are working copies of the tracked files. Those tracked files cover multiple commits, so which commit would a mounted drive point to? The HEAD ?

Comment: As commented above, the current question appears to demonstrate a misunderstanding of what GitHub represents. More clarity might help... perhaps we don't understand the question.

Comment: Here is the complete story. A customer wants to backup his repository data but we dont have provision to read Git as of now. Customer roughly said that github will expose all its respository data over SMB (Our backup application has support to backup NAS Shares). So I was searching if GitHub provides any such solution internal where each repository can be a share and we can mount it and then read the files inside it. 
( We even confirmed whether requirement was GitHub or GitLab, the response was GitHub)

Looks like there is nothing as such by git. External Mirroring is the solution